# Search for documents by minimum value of field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter products by their price, and I'm completely stumped as to how to proceed.
Hoping someone can shed some light on this, and maybe point me in the right direction.

#### Concept

Each product has multiple prices.
These prices are valid during a certain date-range.
The actual price of the product at a certain date is the lowest price that is valid on that date.

#### Goal

I want to be able to:

- get the lowest and highest price for a certain date
- filter the products by a max/min price on a certain date

**caveat**: I have simplified the restrictions for the prices for this example, but I'm not able to consolidate the dates so there's only 1 valid per date range.

#### Example

Mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/price-filter-test'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/price-filter-test/_mapping/_doc' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "integer"},
        "name": {"type": "text"},
        "prices": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "price": {"type": "integer"},
                "from": {"type": "date"},
                "untill": {"type": "date"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Test entries:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/price-filter-test/_doc/1' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product A",
    "prices": [
        {
            "price": 10,
            "from": "2020-02-01",
            "untill": "2020-03-01"
        },
        {
            "price": 8,
            "from": "2020-02-20",
            "untill": "2020-02-21"
        },
        {
            "price": 12,
            "from": "2020-02-22",
            "untill": "2020-02-23"
        }
    ]
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/price-filter-test/_doc/2' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product B",
    "prices": [
        {
            "price": 20,
            "from": "2020-02-01",
            "untill": "2020-03-01"
        },
        {
            "price": 18,
            "from": "2020-02-20",
            "untill": "2020-02-21"
        },
        {
            "price": 22,
            "from": "2020-02-22",
            "untill": "2020-02-23"
        }
    ]
}'
```

At `2020-02-20` entries the following prices will valid, correct prices in bold:

- Product A:

  - 10
  - **8**
- Product B:

  - 20
  - **18**

#### Solution

**Min/Max**

I have figured out how to get the min and max values of the applicable prices.
This was pretty doable using aggregations:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/price-filter-test/_search?pretty=true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "query": {"match_all": {}},
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "product_ids": {
            "terms": {"field": "id"},
            "aggs": {
                "nested_prices": {
                    "nested": {"path": "prices"},
                    "aggs": {
                        "applicable_prices": {
                            "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {"range": {"prices.from": {"lte": "2020-02-20"}}},
                                        {"range": {"prices.untill": {"gte": "2020-02-20"}}}
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "min_price": {
                                    "min": {"field": "prices.price"}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "stats_min_prices": {
            "stats_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "product_ids>nested_prices>applicable_prices>min_price"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Here I first aggregate over the different ids, to ensure prices are checked per product, then I filter by applicable dates, and then get the min prices for each.
Using the **stats_bucket** aggregation, I'm then able to get the min and max values of these minimum prices.

```
{
  // ...
  "aggregations" : {
    // ...
    "stats_min_prices" : {
      "count" : 2,
      "min" : 8.0,
      "max" : 18.0,
      "avg" : 13.0,
      "sum" : 26.0
    }
  }
}
```

Here we see the correct min (8 for Product A) and max (18 for Product B)

**Filtering**

For filtering, I need to be able to exclude products based on their lowest price.
e.g. If I search for products that cost at least `19`, I shouldn't find any as Product B's lowest price is `18`

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/price-filter-test/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "prices",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range" : {
                                "prices.price" : {"gte" : 19}
                            }
                        },
                        {"range": {"prices.from": {"lte": "2020-02-20"}}},
                        {"range": {"prices.untill": {"gte": "2020-02-20"}}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This attempt, however, still yields "Product B" as a match, as one of the prices in this date range is higher than `19`. However, as it is not the lowest price in this date range, it is not the "correct" price.

I'm completely stumped as to how to do this.
I've thought about using scripted fields, but I think I'd need to combine 2 (1 for calculated applicable prices, 1 for getting the lowest), and this doesn't appear to be an option.

Hope you can point me in the right direction

Comment: Can you detail what s you want to do exactly, with an expected result maybe. You try to filter out products using your aggregation result ?

Comment: @LeBigCat Thanks for the pointer, I've updated the quest to provide some more examples.
I'm trying to filter by "correct price", a field that I need to determine at query-time, due to it being context-dependent.
The aggregation is a separate concern I included to make the issue clearer

Answer (score 1):

Well if i right you are looking for inner_hits:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html

I was not sure for the aggregation (you cant inject inner_hits in the aggregation) what s why i didnot post at start.

Hope it s what you need.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "prices",
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "prices.price": {
            "gte": 10,
            "lte": 20
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

=> will keep only nested doc mathing with the range in the inner_hits part:

```
"inner_hits":{
   "prices":{
      "hits":{
         "total":2,
         "max_score":1,
         "hits":[
            {
               "_nested":{
                  "field":"prices",
                  "offset":1
               },
               "_score":1,
               "_source":{
                  "price":18,
                  "from":"2020-02-20",
                  "untill":"2020-02-21"
               }
            },
            {
               "_nested":{
                  "field":"prices",
                  "offset":0
               },
               "_score":1,
               "_source":{
                  "price":20,
                  "from":"2020-02-01",
                  "untill":"2020-03-01"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will allow me to loop over all prices that match the filter. However, I'm trying to filter the products by 1 specific price (their lowest price). Thanks for this one though, hadn't heard of it yet